# Non Super Admin Cannot Edit Entries

Tags: control-panel, super-admin

i was recently informed that a user who has access to the CP cannot edit any entries that were created by a Super Admin past a certain date.  The site is running EE 2.11.3.

In testing, they are able to create entries but any time they edit they get an error that "You are not authorized to access this page."  If I move them to the Super Admin group, they are fine.  I created a new group based on the Super Admin group (with all permissions selected and access to all modules) and moved the user to that group, and they get the error again.  This happen on all channels.

Any thoughts?

** EDIT **
Here is a screenshot of the settings for this group.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you have set under "Channel Assignment" under the Member Group Settings?
Please set it just like below image for reference.

[image]

Comment: They are set to "Yes" for all channels.  In testing, I set all options to "Yes" - just like Super Admin - to see if that would work.  It did not help.

Comment: Can you please give me a screenshot of Member Group Settings?

Comment: I just edited my original post with a screenshot.